# User authentication facebook

Tags: mysql, facebook-graph-api, websocket, access-token

Basically I have an independent websockets server so when I login to Facebook with PHP I want to store the user access token in a MySQL database, then when a user connects to the websockets server and claims a username I want to compare the user provided access token with the one in the MySQL database.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

User access tokens eventually expire, so you would need to update the DB every time the user re-authenticates your app.

Comment: Upon thinking about this method further it no longer seems like a viable option, is there a way I can make sure an access-token is correct within C#?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but ultimately the best way to make sure an access token is correct is if your app can make API calls on behalf of the user. You would need a way to associate a user token with a specific user, which is possible using a database. Facebook offers extended access tokens which last up to 60 days, at which that point the user would need to re-authenticate the app so that you can refresh the extended access token.
I'm running out of characters, but take a look at their server-side flow for PHP and their different types of access tokens and see if that helps